# SonarQube Bulk Delete API

Tags: sonarqube

There is one trademark example everywhere on the net

```
POST api/projects/bulk_delete
```

"Which can be used by passing the project’s ID in the “keys” parameter. I’m no pro in Curl but it should be something like this (code generated in the Postman client) for project with key “daBestProjectKey”:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 10a0e9a1-8dae-a9d1-45f2-0d8e56de999d" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "keys=daBestProjectKey" "http://localhost:9000/api/projects/bulk_delete"
```

What is missing is basically the one thing the bulk delete is supposed to explain i.e how to actually bulk delete multiple projects?
Are the project keys/Ids going to be comma separated?
I am trying to execute it by Ajax.
 **Sonar Version** 6.4 (build 25310)

```
   deleteJobs: function (formData, uiCallbackFunction) {
        $.ajax({
            url: self.SONAR_BULK_DELETE_URL,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'multipart/form-data', 
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic YDHGHDGDHGDH==");
            }
        }).done(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
            uiCallbackFunction(xhr);
        }).fail(function (data, statusText, xhr) {
            uiCallbackFunction(xhr);
        });
    },
```

How is formData supposed to be?
I get Error 400 Bad Request

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"ids or keys must be provided"}]}
    var formData = {};
    formData["Keys"] = "daBestProjectKey:test1,daBestProjectKey:test2";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The parameter name has to be **`projects`** (not `Keys`).
2. The value has to be a **comma separated** list of keys.
3. I always provide the parameters as **url parameters**, not form values. I'm unsure, wether form parameters do also work.

An example request, tested with SonarQube 6.6:

```
curl -s -u admin:admin -XPOST "localhost:9000/api/projects/bulk_delete?projects=daBestProjectKey:test1,daBestProjectKey:test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter of formData for the keys must be like below

```
formData["**projects**"] = "daBestProjectKey:test1,daBestProjectKey:test2";
```